PyCharm highlighting docstring keywords
With the default reStructuredText format, PyCharm highlights words such as param, type, raise, and return, such as in the example below:
enter image description here
However, when I try another style such as Google, none of the docstring stub generated is similarly highlighted.
I went to settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools > Docstrings and changed Docstring format to various styles included by default like Numpy and Google, but only reStructuredText has docstring highlighting.

From what I can gather from PyCharm's docs there is only syntax highlighting for reStructuredText and epytext docstrings.

If they really don't support google or numpy docstring highlighting they should really add it.
